# Multithreading Javascript - for each div, save as image

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to solve a big problem. I've seaching a lot here but i did't find a solution.

I have many divs with charts. The charts are for each employee. I can do it, it works.

So, I am using html2canvas for saving the div as a image. It works well.

I can save a div, but the problem is: I have a button and I want to save ALL divs, one by one in a folder.

I am using jquery foreach toiterate all divs (it's correct). But the screen freezes. I've tried with setTimeout and other solutions. But Javascript is single-thread.

So, I read about HTML5 Workers. I did a example with it, but the problem is: WORKERS CAN'T ACCESS DOM. And I use Jquery or Javascript to access the divs. How can I solve this?

Comment: Show us what you have. make a [mcve] and post it here (in the question itself).

Comment: There isn't much you can do... Would it be possible for you to consider server-side rendering maybe?

Comment: workers can't access the DOM, but you can pass information to them, which could include content originating from the DOM. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers. Or is getting that DOM data the slow part?